# Call a workflow from Javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, workflow

I try to run a workflow from my javascript libary on form load.
But when I send the request, I receive the following error message :

> 'POST http://theDestinationCRM/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web
>   500 (Internal Server Error)'

In the activitylog for the workflow, I see it was not started.

I need to trigger the workflow with a parameter (testinput) and I need to receive the answer of the workflow / the output. 
The worklow is defined as a custom actioin with input and output.

```
function RunWorkflow() { 
    var _return = window.confirm('Are you want to execute workflow.');
    if (_return) {
        var url = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
        var entityId = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
        var workflowId = '8b386814-6a3d-4b3c-93a4-e6aaa1bb0b92';
        var OrgServicePath = "/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web";
        url = url + OrgServicePath;
        var request;
        request = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\'>" +
                      "<s:Body>" +
                        "<Execute xmlns=\'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services\' xmlns:i=\'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\'>" +
                          "<request i:type=\'b:ExecuteWorkflowRequest\' xmlns:a=\'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts\' xmlns:b=\'http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2011/Contracts\'>" +
                            "<a:Parameters xmlns:c=\'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic\'>" +
                              "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>" +
                                "<c:key>EntityId</c:key>" +
                                "<c:value i:type=\'d:guid\' xmlns:d=\'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\'>" + entityId + "</c:value>" +
                              "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>" +
                              "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>" +
                                "<c:key>WorkflowId</c:key>" +
                                "<c:value i:type=\'d:guid\' xmlns:d=\'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\'>" + workflowId + "</c:value>" +
                              "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>" +
                              "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>" +
                                "<b:key>testinput</b:key>" +
                                "<b:value i:type='c:string' xmlns:c='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>Some Text</b:value>" +
                              "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>" +
                            "</a:Parameters>" +
                            "<a:RequestId i:nil=\'true\' />" +
                            "<a:RequestName>ExecuteWorkflow</a:RequestName>" +
                          "</request>" +
                        "</Execute>" +
                      "</s:Body>" +
                    "</s:Envelope>";

        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("POST", url, false)
        req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml, */*");
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        req.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Execute");
        req.send(request);
        var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
    }
}
```

And here is the body of the workflow class

```
[Output("testoutput")]
[Default("")]
public OutArgument<String> testoutput { get; set; }

[Input("testinput")]
[Default("")]
public InArgument<String> testinput { get; set; }
protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
{
    ITracingService tracer = executionContext.GetExtension<ITracingService>();
    IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
    IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
    IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

    try
    {
        String input = this.testinput.Get<string>(executionContext);

        this.testoutput.Set(executionContext, input + " aaaand testoutput");
    }
```

Comment: The error is on your server so the client script is unlikely to help.

Comment: @Archer if you are asking for the plugin - it is attached now

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in the webservice and see why it's failing?  A 500 error isn't helpful.

Comment: the plugin got no call - so I can not debug it, because it is not triggered.

Comment: A 500 error means that there was an error whilst executing code on the server.  If your webservice did not receive a call then you would not be receiving a 500 error.

Comment: @Twiebie: you could use Fiddler and intercept the actual response the server is returning. It often contains valuable details.

Comment: Your javascript invocation has something wrong, hence the error. if on-premise you'll find details about the 500 error in the server's Event Viewer (Application events). If you're on 2016 consider moving to the WebaPI (since the SOAP endpoint is currently deprecated)

Comment: You might want to look into this library, which is built to launch CRM workflows from JavaScript: https://processjs.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you, i have used callAction to get my workflow working and handle the input & output params